# "Parecido com" ou "parecido a?"

Tags: expressões

Sempre achei que "parecido a" estava errado, mas recentemente encontrei [esta página no Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-regencia-de-parecido/22118) que diz:

> Com o adjectivo **parecido**, pode-se usar **com** e **a** (...). Porém, o uso indica que **parecido com** se usa mais do que **parecido a** (...).

No entanto, [esta outra página no mesmo site](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-regencia-de-parecido-novamente/31477) indica, pelo contrário, que "parecido com" é a forma correcta da expressão.

Existem fontes mais conclusivas — e que não dêem uma no cravo e outra na ferradura! — que indiquem qual a forma correcta, ou se estão de facto as duas correctas?

Comment: Note-se que o artigo do ciberdúvidas que diz que se podem usar ambos também diz que "parecido a" aparece apenas 3 vezes no Corpus do Português (vs 49 de "com"), e «apenas nos contextos em português do Brasil».

Comment: Não me importa muito o quanto uma das expressões é mais usada do que a outra, mas antes se estão ambas correctas ou não... para ver se não ando a corrigir pessoas erroneamente :P

Comment: Nunca li nem ouvi alguém usar "parecido a".  Soa tão estranho que eu teria percebido.

Comment: Será que alguém poderia me explicar porque se sai algo no Ciberdúvidas e no Priberam, como pode haver dúvida?  É preciso tanta "algazarra"? :)

Comment: A dúvida, @Lambie, é que o Ciberdúvidas parece ter informações que discordam uma da outra...

Comment: @JNat Certo, só que não discorda do Priberam (ou é da??). Muitas vezes o Priberam mostra os dois.

Comment: @Lambie  O fato de eu dizer que "nunca li e nem ouvi", não significa que não exista.  Para mim, significa apenas que em pt-BR essa forma ou é muito pouco usada, ou tem seu uso restrito a uma determinada região do país.

Comment: @Centaurus Pessoalmente, eu diria: Ele é muito parecido com o pai" mas: esses resultados são muito parecidos aos sei-lá-o-que etc. ou seja parecido a algum antecedente, e parecido com quando não há antecedente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que ambas formas estão corretas.

O site [Flip - Dúvida Linguística](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/2236), demostra duas corretas, inclusive cita o Dicionário de Regimes de Substantivos e Adjetivos de Fernandes Francisco (que não tenho acesso).

> Diz-se parecido a ou parecido com? Por exemplo, parecido ao Pai ou
>   parecido com o Pai? Ambas as formas estão correctas? Armando Duarte
>   (Portugal)
>
> O adjectivo parecido pode ser regido, tal como o verbo parecer de que
>   deriva, pelas preposições a e com. Assim, ambas as expressões que
>   refere estão correctas, assim como correctas estão as frases parece-se
>   ao pai e parece-se com o pai.
>
> Bibliografia: Francisco FERNANDES, Dicionário de Regimes de
>   Substantivos e Adjetivos, São Paulo, Editora Globo, 1948, p. 286.

Achei também no site [Linguagista](http://linguagista.blogs.sapo.pt/parecido-aparecido-com-1482463), fazendo uma correção com vários trechos, dizendo que ambas formas estão corretas.

> Só ontem me disseram: no programa Pontapés na Gramática, na Antena 3,
>   Sandra Duarte Tavares, a 5 de Novembro passado, afirmou: «A explicação
>   é breve, concisa, objectiva, como nós gostamos aqui no nosso Pontapés
>   na Gramática, e diz assim: o adjectivo parecido rege, ou seja, é
>   acompanhado da preposição com e não da preposição a. O adjectivo que
>   gosta da preposição a é o adjectivo semelhante. “X é semelhante a x”,
>   “x é parecido com y”. E por causa do semelhante, por contaminação do
>   semelhante há tendência para dizermos “parecido a”. Não se esqueçam,
>   queridos ouvintes, de que o adjectivo parecido pede, é acompanhado da
>   preposição com.» Joana Dias ainda voltou a perguntar-lhe se não se
>   podia mesmo usar a construção parecido a. «De todo. Não, não, não. De
>   todo. É um erro sintáctico.»
>
> Pena é que esta lição não tenha efeitos retroactivos. Veja aqui os
>   alunos que aproveitariam dela:
>
> «Por esta causa Henrique Harfio, Varão iluminado, e um dos Doutores
>   mysticos, e espirituaes da primeira classe, tratando dos actos
>   anagogicos do amor Divino, ou jaculatorias abrazadas, adverte que pode
>   este exercicio ser puramente natural, e por elle adquirir-se hum amor
>   muy **parecido ao** Divino, porém que realmente o não seja; antes que pôde
>   com elle a Alma andar em estado de condenação» (Luz e Calor, P.e
>   Manuel Bernardes).

No dicionário [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/parecer), também é possível encontrar as duas formas.

> 4. Assemelhar-se, ser conforme (ex.: ele parece-se com o pai; esta música **parece-se a** outra que já ouvi).

Comment: Eu gosto mais dos exemplos do Padre António Vieira e do Bocage, por os achar mais conhecidos.

Comment: "Parecido com o Divino" soa como "parecido com uma pessoa chamada Divino"; talvez daí a mudança na regência. Ou talvez se deva à elisão ("parecido ao [amor] Divino")?

Answer (score 0):

Português do Brasil pode aceitar, provavelmente, ambas as formas (desconheço) - mas em PT-PT, tal como explicado na radio Antena 3, apenas "parecido com"  e "semelhante a" está correto. O resto é confusão entre ambas as expressões e está errado.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.